# select the tab opened by a button click

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs

I have a form with a button in it. If i click the button another form opens. If I return to the parent form with the help of tab and click the same button again it does nothing.

Here is my code:

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             form wadd = new form(this);
             if ((IsFormAlreadyOpen(typeof(form))) == null)
             {
                 wadd.MdiParent = Form1.ActiveForm;
                 wadd.Show();
             }          
        }
 public static Form IsFormAlreadyOpen(Type FormType)
        {
            foreach (Form OpenForm in Application.OpenForms)
            {
                if (OpenForm.GetType() == FormType)
                    return OpenForm;
            }
            return null;
        }  



private void Form1_MdiChildActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.ActiveMdiChild == null)
                tabForms.Visible = false;
            // If no any child form, hide tabControl 
            else
            {
                this.ActiveMdiChild.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                // Child form always maximized 

                // If child form is new and no has tabPage, 
                // create new tabPage 
                if (this.ActiveMdiChild.Tag == null)
                {
                    // Add a tabPage to tabControl with child 
                    // form caption 
                    TabPage tp = new TabPage(this.ActiveMdiChild.Text);
                    tp.Tag = this.ActiveMdiChild;
                    tp.Parent = tabForms;
                    tabForms.SelectedTab = tp;                                      

                    this.ActiveMdiChild.Tag = tp;
                    this.ActiveMdiChild.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(ActiveMdiChild_FormClosed);
                }
                else
                {

                    tab();
                }

                if (!tabForms.Visible) tabForms.Visible = true;

            }
        }
        public void tab()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < tabForms.TabCount; i++)
            {
                if (tabForms.TabPages[i].Text == this.ActiveMdiChild.Text.ToString())
                {
                    tabForms.SelectedTab = tabForms.TabPages[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void ActiveMdiChild_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Destroy the corresponding Tabpage when closing MDI child form
            if (tabForms.HasChildren)
            {
                ((sender as Form).Tag as TabPage).Dispose();
            }            
            //If no Tabpage left
            else if (!tabForms.HasChildren)
            {
                tabForms.Visible = false;                
            }            
        }

        private void tabForms_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((tabForms.SelectedTab != null) && (tabForms.SelectedTab.Tag != null))
                (tabForms.SelectedTab.Tag as Form).Select();            
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {            
            if (!tabForms.HasChildren)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }            
        }
```

The result I want is when I click the button again the tab should gets focused to this form rather than opening new form which is not permissable.

Comment: I don't see where you tell the form which tab to open... am I missing something?

Comment: Also, what does `IsFormAlreadyOpen` return? BTW, I'm sure there's a better name for that method...

Comment: it is for open form if not returns null

Comment: I can see that in your code. When you debug... what is it returning?

Comment: ok sorry i missed something here..actually it returns my parent form..where i have a code to open the tab,

Comment: i Have now added what i hav in my parent form to open the tab..@M.Babcock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd want something like this:

```
public Form FormOpened<T>()
    {
        foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
            if (typeof(T) == form.GetType())
                return form;

        return null;
    }
```

You could then use it like this:

```
form f = (form)FormOpened<form>();
if (f2 == null)
{
    f2 = new form();
    f2.MdiParent = this;
    f2.Show();
}
else
{
    f2.Focus();
}
```

Tell me if you need any help.

Comment: f2.focus is not working with tab..i really need the else part..if(f2!=null) how can i get the required tab

Comment: What do you mean...? I just don't get what you are asking for.

So there are a whole bunch of tabs, and each tab represents an opened window. When you try and open a window that already has a tab for it, it just sets the selected tab to that one?

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this I believe:

```
form wadd;
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if (wadd == null)
         {
             wadd = new form(this);
         }
         wadd.MdiParent = Form1.ActiveForm;
         wadd.Show();

    }
```

You just have the logic backwards. If there is no form open, then create it then open it. If there is a form already then just use it.